# Run until return with WinDbg

Tags: windbg

In OllyDbg it allow you to run until return, e.g you run into a `ret` or `leave` instruction.

Does WinDbg support that? I didn't find such a function in the menu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to stop before returning, you can use `pt`. If you want to stop after returning, use `gu`. The latter is on the Debug menu as "Step Out" with the hotkey Shift+F11.

These and more are listed on the ever-useful windbg.info ([this page](http://www.windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html) in particular).